# Modify MySQL column base on current time

Tags: mysql, database

I have a 'task' table containing Task ID(Primary key,auto-increment), Task status(complete/not complete/expired) and an expiry date(datetime).

Is there a way to update the task status column in MySQL based on current datetime? e.g automatic change task status to set to expired after expiry date > Current Time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [MySQL EVENT Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) to set up a repeating event that updates all tasks to expired if your condition passes.

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.task SET status = 'expired' WHERE expiry_date > NOW();
```

See documentation for more details. Remember you must [enable the event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html) before it will run.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Will be closing this thread due to possible duplicate too